# Populate a List <> not a Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to c sharp.  I"ve got an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0 project and I need to populate a list inside a model and return that model to the page.  My model looks like this:

```
public class PageModel
     public string Title {get; set;}
     public List<ChartGroups> Chart { get; set; }    

}

public class ChartGroups
{
    public string Freq { get; set; }    
    public string Head { get; set; }
}
```

To populate this I've got the following:

```
public PageModel GetChart(){
 PageModel R = new PageModel(); 

 R.Title = "Some Title";
 R.Chart.Add(New ChartGroups {Freq ="Test", Head="Test2"});
 R.Chart.Add(New ChartGroups {Freq ="Test3", Head="Test4"});
 return(R);
}
```

The problem is I get an error saying I need to obstinate the object when I get to the R.Chart.Add... line.  I've been doing this with drop down list and it works just fine....I'm sure I'm missing something simple just can't see it.

UPDATE:
I know that I need to obstinate the object, just not sure how to do so under this context.

Comment: You cannot call `Add()` to a un-instantiated List variable.  In your `PageModel` constructor you should initialize the property: `Chart = new List<ChartGroups>();`

Comment: It means you have to initialize `R.Chart` to an instance before you can access it's members. Your method could also be simplified to one return statement: `public PageModel GetChart() { return new PageModel { Title = "Some Title", Chart = new List<ChartGroups> { new ChartGroups { Freq = "Test", Head = "Test2" }, new ChartGroups { Freq = "Test3", Head = "Test4" } } };`

Comment: mm8 and tjugg both are great answers and I've upvoted both.  If I could I would mark both as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the `List<ChartGroups>()` before you can start adding items to it. You can either do this in your `GetChart()` method:

```
public PageModel GetChart()
{
    PageModel R = new PageModel();

    R.Title = "Some Title";
    R.Chart = new List<ChartGroups>(); //< ---
    R.Chart.Add(New ChartGroups { Freq = "Test", Head = "Test2"});
    R.Chart.Add(New ChartGroups { Freq = "Test3", Head = "Test4"});
    return R;
}
```

Or in your `PageModel` class:

```
public class PageModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<ChartGroups> Chart { get; set; } = new List<ChartGroups>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Initialize the List. So for example, in your PageModel constructor you can do:

```
public class PageModel  
{
    public PageModel()
    {
        Chart = new List<ChartGroups>();
    }

    public string Title {get; set;}
    public List<ChartGroups> Chart { get; set; } 
}
```

Just to inform, you don't probably need the { set; } part of the Chart property since you are now initializing the property in the constructor, so you can just put it as

```
 public List<ChartGroups> Chart { get; }
```

And then, if you wish, you can also you syntax like

```
 public List<ChartGroups> Chart { get; } = new List<ChartGroups>();
```

Which would allow you to move the initialization out of the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Your list is null. So set it to an instance:

```
public List<ChartGroups> Chart { get; set; } = new List<ChartGroups>()
```

Comment: Who are you asking to? Please edit your answer and explain it